# NSThread, UITableViewCell and Image

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsthread

I am having some problem with my UITableView. I am downloading the data and setting up the cells like usual, but this time with the NSThread added.

First I will call ASIHTTPRequest in my view did load

Then in - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request I will add the url of the thumbnail into an NSMutableArray

```
 NSString *photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://some.url.com/img/%@",[thearray objectForKey:@"tn_url"]];    
[thumbNailURL addObject:(photoURLString)];
```

And in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: where I am setting up other data to display, I will call my NSThread

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadImage:) toTarget:self withObject:indexPath];
```

And in my loadImage thread

```
- (void) loadImage: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *iconURL = [thumbNailURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:iconURL]; 
UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11.0, 6.0, 61.0, 50.0)];
[cellImageView setImage:icon];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.contentView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:cellImageView waitUntilDone:NO];
[pool drain];
```

}

All the data and image loaded just fine, but if I scroll faster up and down , the application will hang with the following error

```
[1997:7a1f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'    (0x31312d2f 0x345f50e3 0x3127d1b1 0x35aefc1d 0xf4dd 0x333ffb51 0x3347c67b 0x366af589 0x366b2310) terminate called throwing an exceptionProgram received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

It would be great if anyone could show me the correct configuration if I am wrong, as I have been trying different approaches for the past 3 days already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things.

First, I would recommend you consider using something like SDWebImage for async image downloading (looks like Olivier Poitrey is the original author). Github repository here: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.  I use it for this very purpose and it's great.

That said, I see a few things here.

1) You don't seem to be checking if the cell image is already set... no need to re-download the image if you've already got it.  You might get away with this since `dataWithContentsOfUrl` might offer some caching, but I'm not sure.

2) I can't tell from the code here, but you need to be sure you don't allow the table view to load it's data until *after* `requestFinished` is called.  Otherwise you'll have a race condition that could cause the type of error you are seeing.  Consider setting the tableView's data source in the `requestFinished` method and then calling reloadData.  Otherwise, do as downed suggested and just prefill the URL array with `[NSNull null]` objects.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your great help, SDWebImage works so great! And so easy to integrate.

And to cover what I have missed in my question, yes, i didn't check if the image is existed, and I guess it download everytime when the cell resuse and caused the crash (though i am not sure where should i integrate the check); I actually have a placeholder cell setup if the async hasn't finish and once it is finished, it will reloadData. So everything is fine up to the point of the NSThread.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried having the array "thumbNailURL" contain [NSNull null] objects for the number of items that you are trying to display, then replacing them after you load them async, that way you can't be faster than the array.

```
thumbNailURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < [items count]; i++) {
    [thumbNailURL addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

Then simply:

```
[thumbNailURL replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:thumbnail];
```

Comment: thanks, but I believe it's the NSThread which caused the problem, not the Array, I have a blank loading cell configured if the async request hasn't finished or returns no result.  Without the NSThread loading image part, everything is just fine. So, there must be some problem to it which I couldn't figure out >,<